# Updating global.xml on disk doesn't update geoserver config

Tags: geoserver

I'm using geoserver 2.19 and tried to update directly global.xml to update the contact information but when reloading the cache, it just discards my changes and writes back the global.xml without my changes.

I tried modifying the logging.xml as well, the change I made is visible in the GUI when reloading the cache but is not really adapting the logs as per the modifications I've made.

Am I missing something?

To give a bit more information, I have 2 instances of Geoserver and when I make changes to 1 instance, I call the rest reload to apply the changes on the other instances too. I've read about JMS clustering but it seemed a bit too complex and rigid for what I need to do. Advices are welcome.

I am trying to achieve this : https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/clustering/clustering/passive/passive.html. But I'm having trouble with the synchronization between the instances

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Basically, don't do that!** GeoServer manages that file and you can break things very badly if you mess with that file.

You should **only** change things like contact information through the [GUI](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/contact.html) or the [REST API](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/settings.yaml).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ian. I was able to modify users(add, change password) though directly on the disk and there is a parameter on the user service to specify polling interval. I can also modify any files in the workspaces folder and that works after : https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/rest/api/reload.html

Comment: is there any documentation about which files can be modified and which ones not?

Comment: None of the files can be safely modified - use either the GUI or the REST API

Comment: I was assuming it was possible as per the statement "This operation is used in cases where an external tool has modified the on-disk configuration" on the rest reload page I mentioned in my previous comment. I edited the question about clustering, any advice please?